# Mathematical way of identifying wrong suggestions or outliers

Tags: outlier

I have a hypothetical scenario where i have 100 classifiers to which if a person's name is given as input, it will return a class for the person.

Eg.
**Input1 -`Donald Trump`**

30/100 classifiers returns `politician` as the class
20/100 classifiers returns `business man` as the class
10/100 classifiers returns `leader` as the class
10/100 classifiers returns `american` as the class
10/100 classifiers returns `republican` as the class
10/100 classifiers returns `sportsman` as the class
3/100 classifiers returns `priest` as the class
3/100 classifiers returns `doctor` as the class
2/100 classifiers returns `engineer` as the class 
1/100 classifiers returns `indian` as the class 
1/100 classifiers returns `sportsman` as the class

In the above case i take 10 votes as a threshold, i can somewhat correctly define Donald Trump, though a definition of `sportsman` might be wrong. However 10 seems to be a decent threshold

**Input2 -`Christiano Ronaldo`** 
20/100 classifiers returns `sportsman` as the class 
20/100 classifiers returns `foot ball player` as the class 
13/100 classifiers returns `real madrid` as the class 
13/100 classifiers returns `manchesterunited` as the class
12/100 classifiers returns `juventus` as the class 
12/100 classifiers returns `european` as the class 
2/100 classifiers returns `portugese` as the class
2/100 classifiers returns `cricketer` as the class
2/100 classifiers returns `american` as the class
2/100 classifiers returns `chinese` as the class
2/100 classifiers returns `korean` as the class

In the above example, if i take 12 votes as the threshold, it correctly defines Christiano Ronaldo, though we might be missing `portugese` tag since its vote is only 2. However we are doing a good job here i guess.

My problem is, if i have an api that returns the votes and class of famous persons this way, what is the best mathematical aproach to dynamically find the best possible threshold value above which i can say that the definition is correct and below which you need to have a look if the classes are correct

Comment: In both your examples you could have taken the logarithm (base 10) of the number of classifiers out of 100, taken the floor of that value (or the ceiling), and neatly divided the two lists into two parts at the same places as your gut feeling led you to.  I don't expect such a simple approach would work in more general cases, but it might get you started.

Comment: what would be your expectation if classifiers distribution looks like `[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]` or `[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]`?

Answer (score 0):

> what is the best mathematical aproach to dynamically find the best possible threshold value above which i can say that the definition is correct and below which you need to have a look if the classes are correct

First, in general it's clear that there's no way to be certain that an answer is correct or incorrect: for instance if for some reason all the classifiers return the same wrong answer, then the threshold condition is satisfied but the answer is wrong.

Now the only way to find an **optimal** threshold to decide whether an answer is acceptable is to use a set of labelled examples in order to evaluate the answers of the classifiers.
Why? Because the correctness of the answers cannot be determined by any mathematical formula.

So the goal of the game is to assess to what extent this set of classifiers can be trusted to give a correct answer, and that depends on the threshold. So the threshold is a **parameter** of the predicting system, and this parameter can be estimated (tuned) based on some validation data. The basic method consists in trying all the possible values for the parameter, evaluate the performance in every case and pick the value which obtains the highest performance. Note that there are many  possible evaluation measures for such a scenario: the measure should be chosen carefully depending on the goal of the system (e.g. is it better to have one false positive answer or false negative?).

Answer (score 0):

If you find that the classes are somewhat correlated (e.g. being a politican and a businessman is extremely likely to be leader) then you can make use of these statistical rules to bypass or post-modify the votes.

Otherwise, I think the best you can do is set a static threshold which gives you the best precision and recall combination.